# Saving a randomly generated picture using Python mechanize

Tags: python, image, mechanize

I want to save a picture from a web that is randomly generated at each request, I tried to get it using .retrieve() but it doesn't work (it downloads another random picture).

I wouldn't mind to download the whole page if necessary.

Comment: Show your code. If image has always the same name/path you could use `curl` in place of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2
referer = 'link of the page of image'
image   = 'image link '

req = urllib2.Request(image)
req.add_header('Referer', referer)   # here is the trick
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

output = open('out.jpg','wb')
output.write(response.read())
output.close()
```

This is the solution of your problem.